# c++ using an array without calling constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, stdmove

My task is to create a template type array without calling the T (template) constructor. After that I want to move some value to this array from another with std::move. How can I do this in c++? Here is my code:

```
void *temp = malloc((end-begin) * sizeof(T));
for (unsigned int i = begin; i < end; ++i){
    temp[i] = std::move(array[i]);
}
```

But it isn't work. The compiler says the following: Subscript of pointer to incomplete type 'void'.

Comment: Wow, using raw malloc with the tag of C++11?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include 
the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary 
to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem 
statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and 
Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Look at *placement new*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array of `void` makes no sense. [`void`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Void_type) is an incomplete type (and has no size), so `temp[i]` generates the error you're seeing.

To achieve what you want to do, why not use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), and push items into it as they become available ?

```
std::vector<T> temp;
for (unsigned int i = begin; i < end; ++i){
    temp.push_back(std::move(array[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do it by hand, you're looking for *placement new*. First you allocate a "raw buffer" of `unsigned char`s:

```
unsigned char* buf = new unsigned char(end-begin);
```

or:

```
auto buf = std::make_unique<unsigned char[]>(end-begin);
```

and then you write things like `new (buf) T`, `new (buf+sizeof(T)) T`, `new (buf+2*sizeof(T)) T` to "emplace" your objects into that memory space.

The problem is, in the above example I've completely ignored alignment requirements, which is dangerous.

So, instead of replicating what memory pools and `std::vector` do, just use `std::vector`!

```
std::vector<T> vec;
vec.reserve(end-begin);
for (unsigned int i = begin; i < end; ++i){
   vec.push_back(std::move(array[i]);
}
```

and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

As others point out `void` has no defined size so `void*` can't be indexed as an array.

Where does `temp[1]` begin?

A naïve fix of:

`T *temp = std::malloc((end-begin) * sizeof(T));`

Is just as bad when used in conjunction with:

`temp[i] = std::move(array[i]);`

That code will call the assignment operator and if non-trivial will fail when acting on the garbage that is in `temp[i]`. For example, if the assignment explicitly or implicitly de-allocates resources in the assignment target it will operate on the uninitialized `temp[i]` and fail.

If (IF!) you did this the correct code would be:

`std::memcpy(temp+i*sizeof(i),array[I],sizeof(T));`

That line of code is essentially assuming that `T` is a trivially-copyable type.

The first line is assuming objects of `T` have a trivial default constructor.
If `T` has a trivial default constructor most compilers will optimize the element initialization away (which is what I assume the asker is trying to avoid).

So the recommended code (using a `for` loop) is:

```
T* temp= new T[end-being];
for(unsigned int i=begin;i<end;++i){
    temp[i-begin]=array[i];
}
```

NB: This code also fixes a bug in the original code that breaks when `begin!=0`.
The code appears to be copying a sub-section from the middle of `array` to the start of `temp` but forgets to start at index `0` of `temp`.

But the recommended C++ approach to such copying is:

```
T* temp= new T[end-being];
std::copy(array+begin,array+end,temp);
```

Good implementations will determine and take advantage of any bulk memory operations where possible.
So implicitly this should result in `std::memmove(temp,array,(end-begin)*sizeof(T));` if valid.

The only final twist that a compiler might not recognize is that the potentially slightly more efficient

`std::memcpy(temp,array,(end-begin)*sizeof(T));`

Is actually valid in this case because we know `temp` cannot overlap with `array` (let alone the range being copied).

Footnote: As pointed out in the comments the most conventional C++ approach is to use `std::vector` which can normally be assumed to be using these optimizations behind the scenes. However if for some reason re-architecting the application is not possible or desirable this answer provides the valid efficient way of re-writing the code provided.

Comment: well, the C++-approach is to use a vector :)

Comment: @TheTechel Normally true. Indeed under the hood we'd expect `std::vector` to notice the trivialities and use bulk copies and indeed take advantage of `std::memcpy`! But there are (some slight) overheads of `std::vector` and if the poster has some reason to set those aside this is the right way to achieve the outcome without recoding their application...
I will make a note.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
T *temp = (T*) malloc((end-begin) * sizeof(T));
```

Comment: Or use a vector as @SanderDeDycker suggested, it's safer.

Comment: This solves the type problem of the pointer, but if `T` is `std::string` there still is no string at `temp[i]` so trying to assign to it is invalid.